# What is it about mini-pages navigate method Meteor.navigateTo?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Could anyone give me a hint why I have to override the Method Meteor.navigateTo? I Can't find a discription of this method. Seems to be a method of the package mini-pages.

```
// override with mini-pages navigate method
  Meteor.navigateTo = function (path) {
  Router.go(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you'll receive an answer for this; mini-pages was superseded by iron-router which has been superseded by Flow-Router https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router.

I'd suggest you move over to Flow-Router as per the Meteor guide.

Comment: You are right. As explained here [link](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles#roles-docs)

Comment: While investigating the examples of the meteor package alanning:roles for iron/flow router, I found this override method. This confused me.